# Fabric asks for root password

Tags: python, fabric

I am using Fabric to run the following:

```
def staging():
    """ use staging environment on remote host"""
    env.user = 'ubuntu'
    env.environment = 'staging'
    env.hosts = ['host.dev']
    _setup_path()

def bootstrap():
    """ initialize remote host environment (virtualenv, deploy, update) """
    require('root', provided_by=('staging', 'production'))
    run('mkdir -p %(root)s' % env)
    run('mkdir -p %s' % os.path.join(env.home, 'www', 'log'))
    create_virtualenv()
    deploy()
    update_requirements()
```

But I get this:

```
ubuntu@host.dev:~/projects/proj_name$ fab staging bootstrap
[host.dev] run: mkdir -p /home/ubuntu/www/staging
Password for ubuntu@host.dev:
```

Why is Fabric asking for my password? This is the default ubuntu root user which has no password in the sudoers files. What's going on here?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

*meta: Just realized this question is still unanswered. I have no idea what really happened there but here's a guess.*

This was probably caused by failing to use a keyfile when connecting to a machine where plaintext password SSH connection was disabled.

Proper usage would be:

```
fab -i keyfile.pem <fabric_task>
```